# What determines the size of a select element when it is clicked on?

Tags: javascript, html, css, select, element

I have a select element with 22 options in five optgroups.  On some browsers, if I click on the select, it only displays the top 14 options and the scroll bar won't reveal the rest of the options list.  I'm trying to determine what governs the behavior of the select element when it is clicked on, and I'm not having much luck.

In most browsers, everything seems to happen automatically and correctly, but sometimes it's cut off.  I'm hoping to determine what's cutting it off in these browsers and fix it.  When it doesn't work, it looks like this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/spi63bkl290zyfd/SelectIssue.jpg?dl=0

Comment: a plain old `select` is drawn by the user agent.

Comment: If you want more control of your `<select>` then try using a javascript plugin like [select2](https://select2.org/)

Comment: It's decided entirely by the web browser you are using and the OS you are running on.  There's no way to control this via CSS.  Think about how the menu is displayed on a mobile device - it's entirely different and "how many are displayed at once" isn't really represented in the same way either.